# NetBeans replace all occurrences of a method with another?

Tags: netbeans, refactoring

I'm looking for a way to refactor all usages of a method with another. I'm de-singleton-izing a class, and I'm trying to replace all of the `getInstance()` methods with another method.

In my case, I'd like to change all usages of `OldClass.getInstance()` to be `NewClass.getInstance().getOldClass(0)`. Is this possible with NetBeans' refactoring tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Netbeans you can refractor the name of the method, but you can't change C.m() to C.m().m2() with refractoring tools.

So the best solutions is to go with <kbd>Edit</kbd>-><kbd>Replace</kbd> or <kbd>Replace in project</kbd>.

Then replace all `.getInstance()` by  `.getInstance().getOldClass(0)`. (Take care of the scope). Don't worry it doesn't replace all occurence directly, it finds match then it displays a tree with checkboxes, you can click on <kbd>Replace</kbd> to replace the selected occurence.